# Eevee Linear / Cubic Texture Interpolation Complex Node Issue / Bug

Tags: texturing, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, interpolation

A friend has been working on a project, and they have run into issues with using Linear Interpolation & Cubic Interpolation with their complex node tree.
This node tree will be working with low resolution textures for a game, these really can't afford to be enlarged just for the purpose of avoiding these visual issues in Blender.

Linear Issue: Repeating does not work seamlessly, every texture tile has a harsh aliased edge around the border of the texture, no Blend mode or known setting fixes this, it is only present in Linear and occurs no matter if it is Opaque or uses Alpha.

[image]

Cubic (& Smartest) Issue: Clamping the texture does not work for 1 pixel wide gaps in Alpha, as cubic seems to go beyond a single pixel gap of Alpha. The result is not ideal. TO CLARIFY: The problem is not the white border around the texture, that is a simple fix. The problem is that with Cubic/Smart the near outermost pixels are stretched when this Clamp mode is used.

[image]

If anyone has any ideas about solving this, do tell! In the mean time, we use Closest, which is generally not accurate to how the game will handle these low resolution images. .blend (old) contains the node tree, the math that results in these issues is within the "Get UV" group. Interpolation can be adjusted at the Texture 0 Node.

Update: Simpler [.blend](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/291675838309597185/650650354882576397/LinearCubicBug2.blend) nodes with option to Clamp outside of the groups.

Comment: What a branch do you use? Some of nodes (in your linked blend file) are "Undefined" (red) in 2.80 and 2.82 alpha. Some issue can come from combinations, since current node tree is mixing images with Closest and Linear interpolation.

Comment: There is no issue with the current combinations. Technically only one texture is in use and matching them makes no difference. Closest is already the default as I said, this works but it is not accurate to the settings we have available, some form of working interpolation would be great and Linear is the most accurate. The undefined nodes are not a part of the problem, those are normally named by the add-on, the issue in question occurs in the "Get UV" node group.

Comment: To attract more people you could simplified blend into node tree that are you focused (if I understood you right the node tree could be like in my WIP answer, right?)

Comment: Done, there's still a lot of complexity though, the issue stems from the node tree afaik.

Comment: The test image doesn't seem to be packed in the .blend? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Congratulation. Can you provide correct answer for already almost  100 people interested in your Q? Thank you.

Comment: Try again Robin, but any image will have the Linear problem, and any image with a 1 pixel wide gap at the edge of alpha will have the Cubic problem.

Comment: OK, consider to change question to a version in the link. Your screens, note with "alpha", term "clamp" and other small thing can easily confused people (like me). I have a privilage to change your Q (for you, if you think its correct) or do it by your self. I don't want to do without your permission, even you can easily go back to your last edit. https://www.dropbox.com/s/flgsb8zsym9ia1a/Question_Linear-Cubic.zip?dl=0

Comment: What's the purpose of the node group? What is it supposed to do? Can you provide a bit more context? If someone solve this, they will need to go through the maths. It would be helpful to know some context while doing so.

Comment: The nodes customize based on some custom material interface, it's supposed to just visually represent these as accurately as Blender can and it does a pretty fair job at it. The math in "Create Tex Coord.." group, within the "Get UV" group are responsible for displaying the texture coords/UVs properly (one for each axis, Clamping or mirroring if enabled, shifting and so on). Something about the repeating just doesn't like it though, maybe this is just a bug with Blender's Linear interpolation and not something we can fix, idk.

Comment: Feel free to mangle the math inside "Create Tex Coord.." if you must, I just want to understand why Blender aliases for every texture tile.

Comment: So if Texture Generation Flag is 1 it takes Normal vector, converts it to Camera space, adds (1,1,1) to it, divides it's x and y by -2 and multiplies them by 32? What is that for?..

Comment: I can't explain the intricacies very well, that much is probably for environment mapping (which works like a charm) but like I said, you probably want to be looking inside "Create Tex Coord.." for the cause of the tile aliasing.